# send file as a data binary to http post spring boot

Tags: java, html, file, http, post

I have a curl command:

```
curl -X POST "https:example.com/upload" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: token" -H
"Content-Type: text/plain" --data-binary @"filename.txt"
```

this is the code so far:

```
SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            URL url = new URL("https://example.com/upload");
            HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslsocketfactory);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", encodedValue);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
            OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath));
             
            os.write(bytes);
            os.flush();
            
            int respCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println(respCode);

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 404) {
                InputStream inputstream = conn.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
                BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);
while ((client = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.getWriter().println(client);
                }
            }
```

I am getting a 404 response.

can someone help me what am I doing wrong here? Please and thanks.

Comment: What do you do if there is a 404? Depending on the implementation of the API, a 404 can mean more than the general "not found"? Maybe there is some information in the response that can help you debug.

Comment: No, it works fine if I execute the curl command, I get a JSON response back.